# Color Variables on figlet!

Tags: shell-script, colors

I'm Creating a Login Screen when I start my **CLI Arch Linux** and I build a script on the file

> /etc/bash.bashrc

Like as it follows below:

```
#COMMANDS CREATED INSIDE /ETC/BASH.BASHRC FILE
# USING ANSI COLORS
RED="\e[31m"
ORANGE="\e[33m"
BLUE="\e[94m"
GREEN="\e[92m"
STOP="\e[0m"


# LOGIN SCREEN MESSAGE 
screenfetch
printf "${GREEN}"
printf "=================================\n"
printf "${ORANGE}"
figlet -w 200 -f standard "F4NT0 ARCH LINUX"
printf "${BLUE}"
figlet -w 200 -f  small "CLI Operational System"
printf "${GREEN}"
printf "=================================\n"
printf "${STOP}"
```

In the code above, I build the variables who calls the colors and I let **"leak"** on the messages created with the **figlet program** using the **printf**.

This way I can color the messages until the last variable call(the message below stay with the color i call in the variable above), when I call the next variable,the code change the color from the next message and so on until the **STOP** variable who stop the leaking of the colors.

[image: The Login Letters]

I like how it works in my Arch, but programable way I find it "dirty"...

There is a way to add colors(ANSI,tput or others) in the figlet command to become more adequate to add colors inside Scripts in Unix/Linux?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The way I show In this Question is the Best Way to Put Colors on Figlet, the Way a color is putting before the commands is the Only way I find to Make it work, And after I call the next Color,the next line will be Change to The New Color!!

If anyone want to Know, the Way I call the colors is using the ANSI color codes, like Below:

**Regular Colors:**

> - \e[30m = Black
> - \e[31m = Red
> - \e[32m = Green
> - \e[33m = Yellow
> - \e[34m = Blue
> - \e[35m = Purple
> - \e[36m = Cyan
> - \e[37m = White

**Light Colors:**

> - \e[90 = Light Black
> - \e[91 = Light Red
> - \e[92 = Light Green
> - \e[93 = Light Yellow
> - \e[94 = Light Blue
> - \e[95 = Light Purple
> - \e[96 = Light Cyan
> - \e[97 = Light White

The way I use isn´t the only way, not even the complete one

For the Complete Informations About ANSI colors, read this Site:

https://misc.flogisoft.com/bash/tip_colors_and_formatting

About The Variables:

- I put the color name all in Caps because is the best way to avoid Confusion

> GREEN="\e[92m"

- To call the Variable Created, you need to catch the value of the Vaiable, Using the ${} construction

> ${GREEN}

- To make the Color out before the command, you need to use printf to leak the Color(I use Printf but I think echo works too).

> printf "${GREEN}"

- The Next Line who Print Something on the Screen Will have the Color of the Variable.

> printf "${GREEN}"
>
> figlet -f standard "This Will Be Green"

The Text Should Be Like This:

[image: Test]

- To Stop the Color Leak Inside Where it Shouldn´t, there´s Two Steps:

  - If you want to put a New Color, Just Call the New Color
  - If you want to Stop the Color, Use the Following Variable:

> STOP="\e[0m"
>
> - Put the Stop in the End where after that you Don´t want to Change the color like that:

> printf "${STOP}"

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using this pattern:

```
RED_B='\e[1;91m'
GREEN_B='\e[1;92m'
YELLOW_B='\e[1;93m'
BLUE_B='\e[1;94m'
PURPLE_B='\e[1;95m'
CYAN_B='\e[1;96m'
WHITE_B='\e[1;97m'
RESET='\e[0m'

red() { echo -e "${RED_B}${1}${RESET}"; }
green() { echo -e "${GREEN_B}${1}${RESET}"; }
yellow() { echo -e "${YELLOW_B}${1}${RESET}"; }
blue() { echo -e "${BLUE_B}${1}${RESET}"; }
purple() { echo -e "${PURPLE_B}${1}${RESET}"; }
cyan() { echo -e "${CYAN_B}${1}${RESET}"; }
white() { echo -e "${WHITE_B}${1}${RESET}"; }
```

You can then pass the figlet command as an argument to the color functions:

```
bash-5.0# green "$(figlet -f big "Hello!")"
```

[image]

Comment: I just noticed Armbian has nicely colored bigtext ASCII hostnames on ssh/login, they use [toilet](https://www.maketecheasier.com/figlet-and-toilet-asciify-your-text-art/) for this. From before I remember `figlet` can't layout text with ANSI embedded. So coloring works only per line, unless you write it as a post-process filter on figlet output somehow.